# Versioned import in go using modules fails

Tags: go, go-modules

I want my program to use a specific version of [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go#versioning), so that it is compatible with the target cluster.

However the following syntax:

```golang
import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    clientcmd "k8s.io/client-go@kubernetes-1.12.10/tools/clientcmd"
)
```

which I use to achieve to build my client configuration as follows:

```
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
```

fails with this error message:

> ▶ go run main.go
>   package main
>           imports k8s.io/client-go@kubernetes-1.12.10/tools/clientcmd: can only use path@version syntax with 'go get'

How should I state the particular versioned input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your import to

```
import "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
```

And execute the command:

```
go get k8s.io/client-go@kubernetes-1.12.10
```

The used versions are recorded in the `go.mod` file. The above `go get` will change `go.mod` to depend on the given version. Note that you could also edit `go.mod` manually (but it's better to leave it to the go tool). You only need to modify the import path if you're using versions starting or above `v2`, in which case the major version must be a suffix, e.g.

```
import "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd/v2"
```

**Note:**

After the above `go get` command, the the `go.mod` file will be modified to contain a `require` directive like this:

```
k8s.io/client-go v0.0.0-20190708094436-77c08c6b86df // indirect
```

The reason for this is because go modules require semantic versioning, while  `kubernetes-1.12.10` is not a semver2 compatible version number. Still, the go tool will resove that this version tags the [`77c08c6b86df0af19f718d9a57620c4e9b811d48` commit](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/commit/77c08c6b86df0af19f718d9a57620c4e9b811d48), and use it in the `go.mod` file.

Read more about it here: [Go Wiki: Modules: How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies)

Also see: [The Go Blog: Go Modules: v2 and Beyond](https://blog.golang.org/v2-go-modules)